# Trying to limit access to Oracle DB for running queries - Design suggestion

Tags: regex, database, oracle, database-administration

I am working on a web interface to oracle DB wherein :-

1. A user can ask for a access to a PARTICULAR schema
2. If he is granted access he should be able to run queries on ONLY THAT schema.
   (All other queries like Other schemas, sys table, all_tables, dual should be rejected)

I have created a read only user which has access to any table(NOT SYS) in that DB.

Now, the ISSUE I am facing is :-
1. if that DB has two schemas schema1 and schema2 and user has access to schema1 according to the metadata and if he tries to run schema2.table it will run since the read_only user has any_table privilege. 
2. He can run queries on all_tables (which is not idle)

This can be solved by either :-
APPROACH 1 : Creating user for each schema and granting schema.table* privilege to that user.
PROBLEM :- 
1. if there are 100 schemas there will be 100 such users.
2. if there is a new table in schema, need to grant explicit privilege to new tables.

APPROACH 2: I was thinking of using the Regex approach to parse the query supplied by user and only allow schema1.table if he is approved for say schema1. If he tries to run schema2.table it will fail.

PROBLEM :- 
There can be many corner cases like subqueries, joins etc.

Is there a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: A user will always be able to query `all_tables` and `dual`.  I can't imagine why you wouldn't want a user to be able to query `dual`.  And since `all_tables` will always have only the tables a user has access to, I don't see why you'd object to a user being able to query that.  Perhaps you're confusing that with `dba_tables` that lists every table in the database?  If there are 100 schemas and you want users to have access to just 1 schema, why wouldn't you want to have 100 read only roles that you can grant to different users?

Comment: Hey @JustinCave. Thanks for the prompt response. 1. We want to restrict user accessing any table apart from the schema tables even though they might not be critical. I know all_tables is ok to be accessed but we just want schema.table to be the format of the query. 2. Creating 100 users is not a problem. To add new tables and granting them privilege every time is a problem as there can be many tables getting added or deleted in any of these 100 schemas.

Comment: If you were actually able to prevent a user from querying `all_tables` and `user_tables`, virtually any application the user might want to use would fail.  Virtually any database connectivity software you could name depends at some point on the ability to query some data dictionary tables.  If tables are being added and removed, that presumably involves change controls, code reviews, and code promotions.  Including grants to the appropriate roles should be a relatively small portion of this effort that is relatively easy to validate.  Why is that an issue in your environment?

Comment: Its not really an issue. But with this web interface we just want to limit user to be able to query the schema tables. He can query all_tables but if there is a way we can restrict that (which I think can be done through regex), it would be ideal.

Comment: Are you saying that you are creating a web based user interface that allows users to write arbitrary SQL statements that you will execute and that you're trying to limit what that SQL references?  If so, why would you build that interface rather than just giving users SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or access to the web-based query tool in APEX or iSQL*Plus (depending on what version of Oracle you're using)?  If you're going to build an interface that allows users to construct queries, why not give them a limited query builder interface?

Comment: There is some limitation on the environment bcoz of which we removed tools like sql developer to directly access production dbs. I wanted to know more about your idea of the query builder interface, but I think that is like a full blown software in itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83485/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-user2601010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about parsing, it's almost impossible to parse Oracle SQL accurately.  Instead, use the `PLAN_TABLE` populated by
 `EXPLAIN PLAN` to find dependencies.

1. Generate a unique ID for each statement.
2. Generate the execution plan for each statement by running `explain plan set statement_id = 'UNIQUE_ID' for $$SELECT_STATEMENT$$`.
3. Query `PLAN_TABLE` to find the schemas referenced by the query.

Based on some quick testing this appears to work fine for tables, system tables, DUAL, synonyms, and views.

It will not work in at least these cases.

1. Optimizer transformations that remove the table completely from a plan.  For example, the query below references TABLE3 although it doesn't show up in the
   execution plan because it's not used.  These are rare cases and probably not a real problem.

   ```
   select *
   from table1
   where exists (select (select count(*) from table3) from table2);
   ```
2. Procedural code, like functions and types, will not show up in execution plans.  Securing custom procedural code may require a different approach. For example, it may be necessary to dynamically create a temporary procedure with the SELECT statement in a cursor, and then check `DBA_DEPENDENCIES` recursively.

**Examples**

Create a sample schema.

```
create table table1(a number);
create table table2(a number primary key);
```

This query only uses local tables and therefore only returns one user.

```
explain plan set statement_id = '1' for
select *
from table1
join table2
    on table1.a = table2.a;

select distinct object_owner
from plan_table
where statement_id = '1'
    and object_owner is not null;

OBJECT_OWNER
------------
JHELLER
```

This query references system tables and returns the SYS schemas and would fail validation.

```
explain plan set statement_id = '2' for
select (select count(*) from all_objects)
from table1
join table2
    on table1.a = table2.a;

select distinct object_owner
from plan_table
where statement_id = '2'
    and object_owner is not null;

OBJECT_OWNER
------------
JHELLER
SYS
```

This query uses DUAL and should fail validation.  Detecting DUAL is a bit trickier because it is not a real table.

```
explain plan set statement_id = '3' for
select (select count(*) from dual)
from table1
join table2
    on table1.a = table2.a;

select distinct object_owner
from plan_table
where statement_id = '3'
    and object_owner is not null
union all
select distinct 'SYS'
from plan_table
where statement_id = '3'
    and operation = 'FAST DUAL';

OBJECT_OWNER
------------
JHELLER
SYS
```

---

**Disclaimer**

I do not recommend this solution in most cases.  I agree with Justin's concerns about this request.  Managing hundreds of schemas and objects may be simpler if it adheres to the standard Oracle security methods.  And it's best to fight unreasonable "security" requests sooner rather than later.  Unfortunately, in practice those battles are usually lost.

Comment: On a side-note, it looks like you're trying to build a simpler, private [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).  I'm working on an [open-source program](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer) that might help with some steps (some day in the near future, it's not ready for production quite yet).  For example, just classifying statements as SELECT is ridiculously difficult and cannot be done with simple regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are describing a plain client-server scenario.

If your end users are database schemas as your are describing, then you should implement database "roles". Assign objects access to database "roles" and then assign these "roles" to end users according your security definitions.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6014.htm

To avoid the "schema1.table" and "schema2.table" you can implement database synonyms.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm

Using both "roles" + "synonyms" you will have enough control (security) and easy management.

Here you have some Oracle security guidelines:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/guidelines.htm#DBSEG009

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/arch-approach-inf-sec-360705.pdf